# Site collection administrator created through CSOM cannot view site

Tags: permissions, csom, claims-based-auth, claims, role-assignment

I am having a strange situation where I am not able to view a site collection as a site collection administrator. The catch is that I created the site collection admin through CSOM.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create the site collection
2. Create the user with csom and assign `IsSiteAdmin` to the user.

   ```
   using (ClientContext clientContext = getClientContext((string)action["SiteCollectionUrl"])) {

   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site);
   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site.RootWeb);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   UserCreationInformation userCreationInfo = new UserCreationInformation();  
   userCreationInfo.LoginName = "mydomain\\owner3f3f152a7b39";
   userCreationInfo.Title = "Fnowner3f3f152a7b39 Lnowner3f3f152a7b39";
   User spUser = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.SiteUsers.Add(userCreationInfo);  

   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   spUser.IsSiteAdmin = true; 
   spUser.Update();

   clientContext.Load(spUser); 
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   }
   ```
3. Log in as the user and navigate to the site and you will get "you do not have permission to access this site."

If I delete the user that I created from the users page: http://win-d9fm7ip9r36/sites/3f3f15-ec-10cd-4fd5-8973-11f297921cf1/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/user.aspx
Then I recreate the user using the UI, it works fine.

I think the problem is with how I am creating the user.

When I create the user using my CSOM program, the user looks like this:

```
Account     MYDOMAIN\owner3f3f152a7b39
Name    Snowner3f3f152a7b39 Fnowner3f3f152a7b39
```

When I create the user from the UI, it looks like this:

```
Account     i:0#.w|mydomain\owner3f3f152a7b39
Name    Snowner3f3f152a7b39 Fnowner3f3f152a7b39
```

What am I missing? Why is the claims prefix not being added? Is that something we have to do manually?

In other words, should I have done this?

```
    userCreationInfo.LoginName = "i:0#.w|mydomain\\owner3f3f152a7b39";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`web.EnsureUser(loginName)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee540898(v%3Doffice.15)) to add the user?  Also, I stumbled on [this other article](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/what-you-need-to-know-about-using-ensureuser-in-claims-based-web-apps-in-sharepoint-2010-and-sharepoint-2013/) that seems to be saying that if you are using claims, you do need to include the claims prefix as part of the login name.

Comment: confirmed. adding the claims prefix fixes the issue! thanks. Also +1 for the link.